# how do I get a binding of computed property in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a search bar in a list that filters an array of students and stores them in a computed property called `searchResults` of type `[Student]`, I want to pass a `binding` of each filtered student in the list to another view that accepts a `binding`.

If I tried to pass a `binding` of `searchResults` in the list, it says: `Cannot find '$searchResults' in scope`, I think because `searchResults` is not a `state`, and I cannot make it a state since it is a computed property.

```
struct StudentsSection: View {
    @Binding var course: Course
    @State var searchText = ""
    var searchResults: [Student] { course.students.filter { $0.fullName.contains(searchText) } }
    var body: some View {
        List($searchResults) { $student in // error: Cannot find '$searchResults' in scope
            StudentRow(student: $student, course: $course)
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
    }
}
```

I want to achieve the same result as the code below:

```
struct StudentsSection: View {
    @Binding var course: Course
    var body: some View {
        List($course.students) { $student in // no errors
            StudentRow(student: $student, course: $course)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Move the code to search and filter the items into the `course` object.

Comment: I don't think you need all those bindings here at all.

Comment: @Asperi I need to pass a binding to StudentRow to edit the same student, not another copy of the student.

Comment: @vadian can you elaborate, please?

Comment: Make `course` a class conforming to `ObservableObject`, a view model. It's highly recommended to keep all extensive calculations out of the view.

Comment: You can’t use a computed variable, as you have found, but I can’t see why you would need to. You can use a straightforward array, ideally as an `@Published` property in an `ObservableObject` view model. When your search text changes, filter your input array and assign the result to the the `@Published` property

Comment: @Paulw11 is there another solution if my `course` model is a `struct`? not a `class`.

Comment: In SwiftUI your view model should nearly always be a class so that it can be an observable object.  You typically want your model to be mutable